# Implement WordPress Hooks in a Custom Pure PHP Code

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm creating a really huge system in PHP and I would like to make things simpler for me and probably for the future developers.

I'm looking to achieve a functionality where when a certain action is triggered in the system, a custom function is called, just the same idea used by WordPress add_action();

This is exactly what I mean,

For example in WordPress, if one needs to execute code in the header section, a hook called wp_head is used, that's

```
function add_script_to_header(){
    echo "this one will be print in the header";
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_script_to_header' ); 

function another_script_on_header(){
    echo "this onather script on the header";
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'another_script_on_header' );
```

Now that was just an example, I would like to implement the same thing with custom PHP completely independent of WordPress, which means, my code is not in any way related to WordPress.

I've tried to use callable functions in PHP, but at some point, it gets *tongue-twisting*

In my case, I have a class called Orders that records, payments, shift orders from one state to another, and a lot more things, I would like to have a hook or way of triggering action with a function when certain actions are triggered.

The following code indicates some of my trials

```
function next_order($orderId, $status, $autoApprove = 0){
    // this is function that is responsible for shifting orders from one status to another
    // or from one state to another
    // I would like add_action() function to be linked here, so that I can track 
    // order status with external functions
}

function add_action( $action_name, $function_name ){
    if( $action_name == "order_next" ){
        call_user_func( $function_name, $action_name);
    }

    if( $action_name == 'order_placed' ){
        // here we can place an action for that
    }

    if( $action_name == 'order_paid' ){

    }


}

 

function benson_karue( $orderId ){
    echo "This is the order id ".$orderId;
}

add_action( 'order_next', 'benson_karue' );
```

Comment: It seems to me you are missing the one part, i.e. the triggering of the event. You add_action function executes the user function immediately. You'd want a separate class to handle the subscribing and triggering of events. i.e. the add_action stores the action name and user function in that pub sub class. Then when your Order class is ready it calls a "do_action" function on that pub sub class which executes all stored user functions with the same action name. I would suggest if you want to make things easier then use an existing library like Symfony that has this built in.

Comment: There are some projects that mimic that functionality for other systems, in PHP and also in other languages  - for example [This library for lavaral](https://github.com/tormjens/eventy)  you could maybe search a bit or browse the code and see how its built - including browsing the wp code itself.